# Make a query to both "id" or "slug" with a single variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I have a table "articles" where there're "id" and "slug" among other things. On an html page I have a list of links to articles. A link can contain either "id" or "slug" in it.

**But if in a URL there's only a number, it doesn't still mean that it's an id -- therefore, casting to int to determine whether or not it's slug or id, won't work.**

```
  /articles/my_article
  /articles/35 
  /articles/666 --> still may be slug
```

I have this sql query:

```
import (
  "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4"
  //.........
)


// [..........]


vars := mux.Vars(req)
q1 := `
  SELECT
    ar.id,
    [.........]
  FROM
    articles AS ar
  WHERE ar.slug = $1 OR ar.id = $1`

ar := Article{}
row := db.QueryRow(context.Background(), q1, vars["id_or_slug"])
switch err := row.Scan(&ar.Id, /*[.......]*/); err {
case pgx.ErrNoRows:
  wrt.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
  wrt.Write([]byte("article not found"))
case nil:
  // good, article found
```

I get:

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = text (SQLSTATE 42883)
```

Comment: Do `strconv.ParseInt` in Go, if not valid integer result will be `0` and you can ignore the error, pass that int as second argument and use `WHERE ar.slug = $1 OR ar.id = $2`.

Comment: ... or create your own cast in postgres: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10307443/965900

Comment: @mkopriva re-read my question

Comment: I've read it and re-read it, I don't think I've missed anything, unless your question implies that there's a case where one article has id=666 and another article has slug='666' which is bad design but still will work, you just need to decide on the priority of the attributes and order the where conditions accordingly.

Comment: from the two suggestions in the first two comments what specifically do you find is incorrect and won't work as you intend?

Comment: @Rubashka351, you haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: @Peter, no I haven't.

Comment: @mkopriva you're right

Answer (score 0):

You can "attempt" to convert the value to an integer and if the conversion fails just ignore the error and provide an id value known to *not* be present in the db.

Doing the conversion with Go:

```
slug := mux.Vars(req)["id_or_slug"]

// option 1:
id, err := strconv.ParseInt(slug, 10, 64)
if err != nil {
    id = -1 // provide a value that you're certain will not be present in the db
}

// option 2:
// if id 0 is good enough, you can skip error checking
// and use the following instead of the above.
id, _ := strconv.ParseInt(slug, 10, 64)

query := `SELECT ... FROM articles AS a
WHERE a.slug = $1
OR a.id = $2`

row := db.QueryRow(query, slug, id)
```

---

Doing the conversion with postgres: (the following postgres snippet was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306830/postgres-define-a-default-value-for-cast-failures/10307443#10307443).
)

```sql
-- first create a postgres function that will do the conversion / cast
create or replace function cast_to_int(text, integer) returns integer as $$
begin
    return cast($1 as integer);
exception
    when invalid_text_representation then
        return $2;
end;
$$ language plpgsql immutable;
```

... and then utilizing that in go:

```
slug := mux.Vars(req)["id_or_slug"]

query := `SELECT ... FROM articles AS a
WHERE a.slug = $1
OR a.id = cast_to_int($1::text, -1)` // use the postgres function in the go query string

row := db.QueryRow(query, slug)
```