# How to create a primary key using the hash method in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, hash

Is there any way to create a primary key using the hash method? Neither of the following statements work:

```
oid char(30) primary key using hash

primary key(oid) using hash
```

Comment: Why would they work? What do you think "using hash" means? Are you trying to set up a hashed index (if so why)? Are you trying to "hash" some numeric key?

Comment: Why do you want a hash index? It has some serious problems and no benefits.

Comment: To support offline operations, our client programs are allowed to create entities without accessing the database. Thus, we generate the primary keys with UUID-like approach. To index this kind of primary keys, I think hash is more efficient (in term of performance). Also the key is immutable and the order doesn't matter.

Comment: It's not supported, this is the error message I get: ERROR:  access method "hash" does not support unique indexes

Comment: @TomYeh "you think" hash is more efficient? Evidence? I've never seen anyone show that PostgreSQL's rather unloved hash indexes are better than btree for anything, and their removal is frequently contemplated. Don't guess, *measure*. In any case, you can't do it whether you want to or not.

Comment: Just for completeness: they perform almost the same (if you want to select only 1 row), but btree has a little lower actual runtime, f.ex. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/37175/1

Comment: Hash indexes can give faster lookups than btree, perhaps [around 40% faster](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/281652/50610).

Comment: According to my experiments, btree's index size is much smaller if there are a lot of repeated values.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I assume, you meant to use the [hash index method / type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-types.html).

Primary keys are [constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS). *Some* constraints can create index(es) in order to work properly (but this fact should not be relied upon). F.ex. a `UNIQUE` constraint will create a unique index. Note, that *only B-tree currently supports unique indexes*. The `PRIMARY KEY` constraint is a combination of the `UNIQUE` and the `NOT NULL` constraints, so (currently) it only supports B-tree.

You can set up a hash index too, if you want (besides the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint) -- but you cannot make that unique.

```
CREATE INDEX name ON table USING hash (column);
```

But, if you are willing to do this, you should be aware that there is some limitation on the hash indexes (up until PostgreSQL 10):

> Hash index operations are not presently WAL-logged, so hash indexes might need to be rebuilt with REINDEX after a database crash if there were unwritten changes. Also, changes to hash indexes are not replicated over streaming or file-based replication after the initial base backup, so they give wrong answers to queries that subsequently use them. For these reasons, hash index use is presently discouraged.

Also:

> Currently, only the B-tree, GiST and GIN index methods support multicolumn indexes.

**Note**: Unfortunately, `oid` is not the best name for a column in PostgreSQL, because it can also be a name for a [system column and type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html).

**Note 2**: The [`char(n)` type is also discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848964/postgresql-difference-between-text-and-varchar-character-varying). You can use `varchar` or `text` instead, with a `CHECK` constraint -- or (if the id is so uuid-like) the [`uuid` type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html) itself.

Comment: Hash index operations ARE WAL-logged, since PostgreSQL 10.