# Number of columns or their types differ between the queries

Tags: postgresql, pgtap

Using PostgreSQL 9.4.3 on Debian Jessie 64.

question.sql :

```
\set client_min_messages = debug

BEGIN;

SELECT * from no_plan();

SELECT Dugong.Users_Add('Sarit','thisispassword','programmer');
SELECT is(Dugong.Users_isExist('Sarit'),'t', 'Test Question_isExist() should return true' );
PREPARE A AS SELECT Username, Password, Privilege FROM Dugong.Users;

SELECT results_eq('A',$$VALUES ('sarit','thisispassword','programmer') $$,'Test wtf');
SELECT results_eq('A',$$VALUES ('Sarit','thisispassword','programmer') $$,'Test wtf');

SELECT * FROM finish();
ROLLBACK;
```

Output:

```
postgres@jaikra:/home/sarit/4alls/anemonesfish/pgtap$ pg_prove -v -d skorplusdb question.sql
question.sql .. 
Sarit
ok 1 - Test Question_isExist() should return true
not ok 2 - Test wtf
# Failed test 2: "Test wtf"
#     Number of columns or their types differ between the queries:
#         have: (Sarit,thisispassword,programmer)
#         want: (sarit,thisispassword,programmer)
not ok 3 - Test wtf
# Failed test 3: "Test wtf"
#     Number of columns or their types differ between the queries
1..3
# Looks like you failed 2 tests of 3
Failed 2/3 subtests 

Test Summary Report
-------------------
question.sql (Wstat: 0 Tests: 3 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  2-3
Files=1, Tests=3,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr  0.00 sys +  0.03 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.05 CPU)
Result: FAIL
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Dugong.Users
( Username  varchar(255),   
    Password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Privilege varchar(255),
    FirstName       varchar(255),       
    MiddleName  varchar(255),
    LastName        varchar(255),
    StreetAddr  varchar(255),
    Subdistrict varchar(255),
    District        varchar(255),
    Province        varchar(255),
    Country         varchar(255),
    Zipcode         varchar(255),
    Email               varchar(255),
    PhoneCountryCode    varchar(10),
    PhoneAreaCode   varchar(255),
    PhoneNum        varchar(255),
    FaxCountryCode  varchar(255),
    FaxAreaCode varchar(255),
    FaxNum          varchar(255),
    LastModified timestamp with time zone default current_timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY(UserName)
);
```

#### Updates

**Goal**: To test my Users_Add function. Is it hold all the values I gave.
**Expect**: Table Users has 1 record with 3 values.
**My attempt**:
On 2nd error. It shows me 3 columns. That is a good response. Since I intentionaly make it wrong. So in the near future I will let it be a correct one.
However, 3rd error is strange. I copy and change 2nd case to be what I want, let it be uppercase on 'S'. Then prepared query has 3 columns and I check 3 values.
I have another overload function that INSERT INTO all 20 columns. Right now I want only 3. After got the error I go back to document.

**Refer to document error**, it says query and values have different column count. But it is not my case.

**Problem**:
My query has 3 columns and I let `pgtap` check only 3 columns, but 3rd case raises that I am letting it check unequal columns size of record.

Any information about my installation please ask. I will provide them to you as fast as I can.

Comment: Please try to describe the problem. It's great that you've shown code, but I'm not quite sure what the problem you are having is.

Comment: @CraigRinger. Hi, I have added my information. But I am not sure where is the root cause. I am still searching around.

Comment: try turning up the noise `set client_min_messages = debug;`

Comment: @Jasen. Hi I have added \set. Output seems identical.

Comment: no, `set` not `\set`

Comment: Show the definition of `Dugong.Users` (at least the three fields types).

Comment: @Jasen. Without backslash. I got error.question.sql .. psql:question.sql:2: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "BEGIN"
LINE 2: BEGIN;

Comment: you're also missing `;`

Comment: @klin. I add whole table. I am watching pgtap tutorial on vimeo https://vimeo.com/7972197 hope I can find some clue from here.

Comment: @Jasen. I had tried your advice.  ERROR:  function no_plan() does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * from no_plan();

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the number of columns is not a problem, but rather their types. Try this:

```
SELECT results_eq('A',
    $$VALUES (
        'sarit'::varchar(255),
        'thisispassword'::varchar(255),
        'programmer'::varchar(255)) $$,
    'Test wtf');
SELECT results_eq('A',
    $$VALUES (
        'Sarit'::varchar(255),
        'thisispassword'::varchar(255),
        'programmer'::varchar(255)) $$,
    'Test wtf');
```

The problem stems from the fact that the default type for a string (like `'sarit'`) is`text`. Generally, using `varchar(n)` is rather inconvenient when compared to `text`.

More on this topic can be found here: [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings) and [PostgreSQL: Difference between text and varchar (character varying)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848964/postgresql-difference-between-text-and-varchar-character-varying).

Comment: Thank you so much. I want to vote +1 for you, but I can not because my reputation is not enough. Sorry for that.