# PostgreSQL - setting up table for posts - should I use varchar or text?

Tags: postgresql

I am creating a table called Posts in which I want to have:

`id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY`, `title`, `message TEXT`, `created_by INTEGER`.

I am having question on the `title` and `message` fields.

Type `TEXT` is what I want to use for `message`, but what about `title`?  Shall I use `varchar(255)`?

Comment: See [`varchar(any_limit_you_want)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-character.html) - as such the question is an opinion. The impact of different lengths is effectively non-existent, and the slight storage differences are covered in the docs. `text` is the same as saying `varchar(without_a_limit)`. (The varies by database engine, annoyingly.)

Comment: It doesn't matter. From a storage or performance point of view both are identical. And if you think that 255 has some hidden magic or advantage over 200 or 300 then you are mistaken.

Comment: thank you Sir and Sir.  one question, sorry for the beginner level, is if I want to limit the title length to something like 300 chars, what is a good way to do that?

Comment: If you have a business requirement that the length should not exceed 300 then do use `varchar(300)`.

Comment: @RamMudaliar *Read* the link provided .. please.

Comment: Thank you Sir I did read, but one thing I was wondering is I saw another post on this webpage which said in today there is no need to do the varchar(n) and instead to just use text.  But I was wondering to use varchar(300) or use text only.  Sir your link was very helpful and did answer my question.  Thank you

Comment: Hope this helps
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848964/postgresql-difference-between-text-and-varchar-character-varying