# CHECK length limit-n constraint in text field instead vartext(n) use

Tags: postgresql, conventions

SQL language, in particular PostgreSQL 9+, have many ways to do the same thing... But in many circumstances (see Notes sec. for a rationale)  we need to "cut diversity" and opt to a standard way.

There are a [tendency to adopt  `text`  data type instead `varchar`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4849030/287948). Will  be "the standard way to express strings" in PostgreSQL (!),  avoiding lost time in project discussions and casting similar formats...
But, how to use `text` preserving the *size limit constraint*?

I use `CHECK(char_length(field)<N)`  and have no problem to change the limit in live environment, so it is perhaps the best way... **Is it?**

---

Some variations: in general what is the best choice?

1. in `CREATE TABLE`:

   1.1. `CHECK` after the data type, just like default value definitions. This is the best practice?

   1.2. `CHECK` after all column definitions. Usual to multi-column declaration like `CHECK(char_length(col1)<N1 AND char_length(col2)<N2)`.

   1.2.1. Some people like also to express all individual CHECKs after, to not "pollute" column declarations.
2. Use in *trigger*: there are some advantage?
3. Other ways... Other relevant one?

**1.1, 1.2, 2 or 3, what is the best practice ?**

---

### CONTEXT NOTES

In projects and teams with some [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) or [Convention over configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) demands, we need "good practices" recommendations... I was looking for it, in the context of `CREATE TABLE ... text/varchar` and  project maintenance.  No *unbiased "good practices"* recommendation in the horizon: Stackoverflow votings are the only reasonable record of this kind of recommendation.

#### Convention scope

(edit) For individual use, of course, as @ConsiderMe commented, "no matter what you choose, as long as you stick with it throughout the entire time there will be no problem with it".

This question, by other hand, **is about "SQL community"** or "PostgreSQL community" best practices conventions.

Comment: PS: before to vote to close, explain here your view.  Is a question about convention.

Answer (score 2):

I like to keep the code as short as it's possible so it'd go with `length(string)` in the CHECK constraint. I do not see a particular use for `char_length` in this case - it takes up more "code space".

Internally, they are both `textlen` anyways.

You should be careful about signs that take more than 1 byte. In this case I would use `octet_length`. As an example consider character `ą` which returns 1 when asked for length, and 2 when asked for octet_length. It's been a pain doing migrations between database systems with different length enforcement.

---

I believe that a good source for "best practices" would be to follow [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html).

It says that using `CHECK` constraint inline with a column implies a column constraint which is bound to a particular column.

It mentions table constraint which is written separately from any column definition and enforces data corectness between several columns.

Basically in projects I'm involved I follow this rule for readability and maintenance purposes.

I wouldn't even consider creating trigger for such things. To me they are designed for much more complex tasks. I don't see a reason to enforce simple data correctness rules in triggers.

I can't think of any other solution which would be as basic as the standard ones and still doing it's simple job as those mentioned above.

Comment: As I say "have many ways to do the same thing"... The SQL-scale problem repeats as function-scale problem: `length(x)` = `char_length(x)` = `length(x,'utf8')` (you can test for x=`josé ą`). What is the "canonical" name? The [Guide](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) not say what is an alias and what is the original function.  About use `octet_length`: the best practice is to avoid use of this function (!), because today (2016) the universal encode is UTF8, and the default semantic is "count the UTF8 characters". This is also a rationale for use `char_length`.

Comment: The PG Guide as "source for best practices", I agree for many contexts, but in the  context of this quetion,  it is being silent. It is also not unbiased:  1) some [Conflict of interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict_of_interest), because to "show diversity" is something like a "branding strategy"; 2) it is "not so open"  to the community, like ex. Wikipedia or a "please comment here" page. There are  nothig as a "[stakeholder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stakeholder_(corporate)) body" in  pg community... so I say that SO is the "reasonable record of this kind of recommendation"

Comment: Ops, sorry the long "meta discussion", the main comment is here:  "1.1, 1.2, 2 or 3, what is the best practice?", I'm understanding that  your choice is **1.1**, is it?  1.1 with some considerations.

Comment: @PeterKrauss yes, it is 1.1. But no matter what you choose, as long as you stick with it throughout the entire time there will be no problem with it

Answer (score 2):

The [Depesz article](http://www.depesz.com/2010/03/02/charx-vs-varcharx-vs-varchar-vs-text/) on which this reasoning was based is outdated. The only argument against `varchar(N)` was that changing `N` required a table rewrite, and as of [Postgres 9.2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-9-2.html#AEN136313), this is no longer the case.

This gives `varchar(N)` a clear advantage, as increasing `N` is basically instantaneous, while changing the `CHECK` constraint on a `text` field will involve re-checking the entire table.