# What is the maximum length of TextField in django while using PostgreSQL

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-models, textfield

i wanna known what is the maximum length of TextField in django models while using  PostgreSQL.. I just know Mysql uses the longtext data type to store the content, which can hold up to 4 Gigabytes but i wanna know what is the maximum length of TextField in django models while using  PostgreSQL and if can increase it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a maximum length when storing into PostgreSQL TEXT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39965834/is-there-a-maximum-length-when-storing-into-postgresql-text)

Comment: A textfield doesnt have a maximum length. columns have, for postgreSQL thats 1GB

Comment: I got it.. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Both TEXT and VARCHAR have the upper limit at 1 Gb, and there is no performance difference among them (according to the PostgreSQL documentation).

Comment: i got it. Thank you very much :)