# Maximum size allowed for a json and jsonb column in postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

Is there a way for me to find out the maximum size of the data allowed in a json or jsonb column in Aurora postgres?

I tried querying `information_schema.columns` for `character_maximum_length` field, but that just turns up empty.

Comment: There is no theoretical size limit. And the practical one is "huge".

Comment: Probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39966079/1048572) or [that](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/189895/188406) apply to JSON as well. (Not sure about JSONB)