# Data Types in Ecto - "value too long for type character varying(255)"

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

> ERROR 22001 (string_data_right_truncation): value too long for type
>   character varying(255)

I understand (and assumed) that a string would be limited to a certain number of characters; however, I am not sure what type would be best for this scenario.

What type should I be using for a 'content' section of a blog in Phoenix framework?

The data will be paragraphs of text and cannot be limited in size.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The error you get is from the underlying database where the column type is set to `varchar` which is what's created by default when you specify the column type as `string` in a migration.

To store a variable length string over 255 characters, you need to specify the column type as `text` in the migration. You can convert the type of the existing column to `text` by using a migration such as:

```
alter table(:posts) do
  modify :content, :text
end
```

The field type in the schema section of the model should remain as `string`:

```
schema "posts" do
  field :content, :string
end
```

Comment: That's an interesting solution; didn't realize the `:text` type is available in migrations.

Comment: Yeps! There's a bit about it here: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Migration.html#module-field-types

Comment: It sounds like there are NO downsides of using :text.  I'm surprised it's not the default for :string - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4849030/2062384

Comment: @Freedom_Ben It really depends on your database constraints. If someone threw the bible into some :text field on a lot of accounts, you'd start growing your database by 1 bibles worth of data for each time someone did that. It can cause your database to get very big which might be a problem.

Comment: The field types docs are now here: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/3.11.1/Ecto.Migration.html#module-field-types