# PostgreSql text to varchar with concat_ws

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL and I need fields as strings not text.
Here is the statement

```
select AutoNbr, 
       concat_ws(', ', Site_Street, Site_City, Site_Country, Site_PostCode) as cFullAddress , Order_Date 
from Porder
```

What I need is the cFullAddress to be a varchar not a text field.

Comment: Why do you think you need that? Those two type are essentially identical in Postgres

Comment: The Delphi grid I am using sees the difference between Text (memo) and a string. The grid just said (memo) not the string information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documents](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-character.html):

> If character varying is used without length specifier, the type accepts strings of any size. The latter is a PostgreSQL extension.
>
> In addition, PostgreSQL provides the text type, which stores strings of any    length. Although the type text is not in the SQL standard, several other SQL database management systems have it as well.

But you can cast it into varchar;

```
select AutoNbr, 
 concat_ws(', ', Site_Street, Site_City, Site_Country, Site_PostCode)::varchar as cFullAddress , Order_Date,
 CAST(concat_ws(', ', Site_Street, Site_City, Site_Country, Site_PostCode) as VARCHAR)
from Porder
```

Related link for using cast: [type cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS)

[Difference between text and varchar (character varying)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848964/postgresql-difference-between-text-and-varchar-character-varying)