# Postgresql array encoding in Doobie – text[] vs varying[]

Tags: postgresql, scala, implicit, doobie

Suppose we have this postgresql schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "temp" (id  int, fields text[]);
INSERT INTO "temp" VALUES
  (1, array['abc', 'def']),
  (2, array['abc', 'def', 'jkl']),
  (3, array['abd', 'def']),
  (4, '{"1{c}1", a}');
```

The following works in plain SQL, returning rows 1 and 2 (`@>` is the "contains" operator in pg):

```sql
SELECT id, fields FROM temp WHERE "fields" @> '{def, abc}';
```

But the same in [Doobie](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/) (with its postgresql extension):

```scala
import doobie._
import doobie.implicits._
import doobie.postgres.implicits._
val searchTerms = List("def", "abc")
fr"SELECT id, fields FROM temp WHERE fields @> $searchTerms"
```

Fails with:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: text[] @> character varying[]
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Casting the interpolated `searchTerms` value to `text[]` seems to solve the problem:

```scala
val searchTerms = List("def", "abc")
fr"SELECT id, fields FROM temp WHERE fields @> CAST($searchTerms AS text[])"
```

Similarly, I can change the type of the `fields` column from `text[]` to `varchar[]` in the database schema to avoid the cast, and that would also compile and return the correct rows.

My main problem is that I don't know why Doobie behaves that way. I will probably run into this same issue again with custom types, so I need to understand why `$searchTerms` decodes into `varying[]` and not `text[]`, and what, if anything, I can do to change this behaviour so that I can keep the `text[]` column type and avoid the cast. I'm guessing there's probably an implicit instance somewhere controlling this, but I couldn't figure out what it is.

Comment: Doobie maps `String` to `varchar` (more info [here](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/12-Custom-Mappings.html)), and I you can't change that easily. Under the hood, text and varchar are the same (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848964/difference-between-text-and-varchar-character-varying)), so migrating your table to varchar makes most sense in that situation I think. 
Regarding unexpected mappings, there are some issues with datetimes with timezones, but other than that I haven't stumbled upon anything else.

Comment: You could also convert to array (which has instances defined) or define your own Doobie Meta instance.