# Generate random date into series

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use this SQL query to generate random data:

```
INSERT into tasks SELECT generate_series(1,3) AS id, 
md5(random()::text) AS business_name, 
select NOW() + (random() * (NOW()+'90 days' - NOW())) + '30 days' AS created_at,
md5(random()::text) AS meta_title,
md5(random()::text) AS status,
md5(random()::text) AS title,
md5(random()::text) AS type
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 3: select NOW() + (random() * (NOW()+'90 days' - NOW())) + '30 ...
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 105
```

What is the proper way to generate random date?

Comment: `select now()` should only be `now()` there is no need to prefix function calls with `select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the `created_at` expression

```sql
INSERT into tasks
SELECT generate_series(1,3) AS id, 
md5(random()::text) AS business_name, 
now() + random() * interval 'P90DT1H' + '30 days' AS created_at,
md5(random()::text) AS meta_title,
md5(random()::text) AS status,
md5(random()::text) AS title,
md5(random()::text) AS type;
```

`(NOW() + '90 days' - NOW())` is equivalent to `interval 'P90DT1H'` because of the summer time one hour shift.

Comment: One additional question: I get now `ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(20)` Can I somehow specify only 2 types of string for example `new` or `in_progress` just for `type` column?

Comment: I do not think so. Better always use `text` instead of `character varying(XX)`. This is more convenient and a bit more efficient. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848964/difference-between-text-and-varchar-character-varying).

Comment: Is it possible to set String max size when I call `md5(random()::text)`? For example I would like to generate random String with 4 characters.

Comment: Yes, use this  expression `left(md5(random()::text), 4)`

Answer (score 1):

you could use either of these syntax

```
INSERT into tasks SELECT generate_series(1,3) AS id, 
md5(random()::text) AS business_name, 
(select NOW() + (random() * (NOW()+'90 days' - NOW())) + '30 days') AS created_at,
-- note that the select is in parenthesis
md5(random()::text) AS meta_title,
md5(random()::text) AS status,
md5(random()::text) AS title,
md5(random()::text) AS type
```

OR

```
INSERT into tasks SELECT generate_series(1,3) AS id, 
md5(random()::text) AS business_name, 
NOW() + (random() * (NOW()+'90 days' - NOW())) + '30 days' AS created_at,
--note select removed
md5(random()::text) AS meta_title,
md5(random()::text) AS status,
md5(random()::text) AS title,
md5(random()::text) AS type
```