# Should I specify a size to a PostgreSQL field when using Prisma?

Tags: database, postgresql, orm, prisma

I'm using Prisma as my ORM and PostgreSQL as my database, so this question applies both to Prisma and Postgres, and I have the following prisma schema:

```js
model Employee {
  id                          String  @id                                     @default(uuid())
  registrationNumber          String  @db.VarChar @map("registration_number") @unique
  fullName                    String  @db.VarChar @map("full_name")
  username                    String? @db.VarChar @map("username")
  email                       String? @db.VarChar @map("email")
  isSapUser                   Boolean @db.Boolean @map("is_sap_user")         @default(false)

  @@map("employee")
}
```

My question is: Should I set a size to my varchar, like @db.VarChar(20)?
If I do set a size, does the database allocate more space? If I don't, does the database uses only what each field occupies?

Comment: For me there's no need to size varchar. See this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848964/difference-between-text-and-varchar-character-varying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848964/difference-between-text-and-varchar-character-varying)

Answer (score 4):

Don't specify a length maximum for database columns unless it is required by the application or you want to create a B-tree index on the column.

The performance will be the same, and PostgreSQL only allocates the space that is actually occupied by the data.

Here is what [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) has to say about `text`, `character varying` and `character`:

> There is no performance difference among these three types, apart from increased storage space when using the blank-padded type, and a few extra CPU cycles to check the length when storing into a length-constrained column. While `character(n)` has performance advantages in some other database systems, there is no such advantage in PostgreSQL; in fact `character(n)` is usually the slowest of the three because of its additional storage costs. In most situations text or character varying should be used instead.

Comment: Thanks! Can you share a source or documentation, please? I need to share with my team :)