# show all distinct field value of few columns in result with comma separated with ordered ascending

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-15

From n number of columns in a table, I want to list a few columns with their corresponding values in comma separated with distinct value.
By default, if we group by a column, we can use string_agg() for other fields to add values in comma-separated. In past, I have done once using string_agg() with 'group by' & another pg function without 'group by'. But, I am not able to recall
For string_agg I am aware of distinct & null handles along with order. If you know the other function, can you also mention how to achieve distinct, null & order if possible.

The requirement is to show filter for a few columns in the listing table

For example table,

[image]

Here, output should be

[image]

Comment: "*In past, I have done once using string_agg() with 'group by' & another pg function without 'group by'*" - not sure what you mean by that. Can you please post the code of that query?

Comment: "*I am aware of distinct & null handles along with order.*" - the just use that? It's really not clear what you mean by "*If you know the other function*"

Comment: @Bergi I meant I have used the queries that can solve this case. But, I can't find those

Comment: @Bergi other than string_agg there is another function that can be used to get the same result. I forgot that function name. That's what I was mentioning. I was under the wrong impression that string_agg could be used only when it should be grouped & I did not know what fields should I provide in group by columns. The solution mentioned cleared my doubt. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use order by inside string_agg() if needed. As id is integer so it need to cast as varchar because string_agg() handles string values.

```
select
  string_agg(id :: varchar(500), ',') id,
  string_agg(distinct name, ',') name,
  string_agg(distinct city, ',') city
from employee
```

Check this url
https://dbfiddle.uk/a_RUrcid

Comment: Use `text`, not some arbitrary `varchar`

Comment: Use character varying instead of varchar...it's depends on developer...

Comment: Sure, [`varchar` is fine as is `text`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4849030/1048572), but the magic number in `varchar(500)` should be avoided