# I can't understand SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

So I've been learning a lot of SQL in school using MySQL , Oracle and SQL Server. So now i need to work with SQLite on a raspberry pi project. The thing I don't understand is datatypes. When you put your field to be int it can only save whole numbers right? And in SQLite it can save integers inside of a int datatype. So i have been reading about it and how SQLite saves data in these groups:

NULL. The value is a NULL value.

INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

REAL. The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating point number.

TEXT. The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).

BLOB. The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.

So it only makes a difference when saving data and not on input? I can't understand it.. How can I make my INT columns not accept integers? Or it isn't possible?

Comment: I don't understand your questions. Could you please add more details and try to be more clear?

Answer (score 4):

The SQLite dialect of SQL is a [dynamically-typed language](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2009/10/03/static-vs-dynamic-typing-of-programming-languages/).  Just like Python will let you create an array of mixed types like `[None, 42, 3.14, 'Hello, world!', b'\x01\x23']`, SQLite will let you store values of multiple types in the same column.

## Storage classes

Conceptually, SQLite has five scalar [data types](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), called “storage classes”:

- The `NULL` type is used for the singleton value `NULL`, which is a sentinel value indicating an unknown or not-applicable value.
- The `INTEGER` type is a 64-bit signed integer.  The part about “stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value” is an implementation detail of the file format, and not something you as a programmer need to be concerned with.  From the point of view of the C API and the SQL language, it's always 8 bytes.
- The `REAL` type is a [64-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) floating-point number.
- The `TEXT` type is a character string.
- The `BLOB` type is a sequence of octets.  SQL literals are `X`-prefixed strings of hex digits (e.g., `X'0123456789ABCDEF'`).

If you're a Python 3.x programmer, you can think of:

- `NULL` = `None` (of type `NoneType`)
- `INTEGER` = `int` (but limited to 64 bits)
- `REAL` = `float`
- `TEXT` = `str`
- `BLOB` = `bytes`

(This is actually the type mapping used by Python's standard `sqlite3` module.)

If you're a C# programmer, you can think of:

- `NULL` = `null` (but without the arbitrary distinction between value types and reference types)
- `INTEGER` = `long`
- `REAL` = `double`
- `TEXT` = `string`
- `BLOB` = `byte[]`

SQLite lets you store a value of any data type in any column.  (Exception: If a column is declared as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, and its table is *not* declared `WITHOUT ROWID`, then it actually is constrained to contain only integers, because it is an alias for the row ID.)

## Column type affinity

*Independent* of the above list of “storage classes”, SQLite has the concept of **type affinity** which determines the *preferred* data type to store in a column.  The affinitity of a column is determine by its declared datatype.

Only numeric (`INTEGER` and `REAL`) and `TEXT` values are affected by these automatic type conversions; there is never any implicit conversion to or from the `NULL` or `BLOB` storage classes.

So, if you declare a column with integer affinity (e.g., `INT` or `INTEGER`), but you insert a text string into it, then SQLite will automatically convert the value to an integer for you.  But if it can't, it leaves it as a string.  So, the string `'42'` becomes the integer `42`, but the string `'xyz'` stays as-is.

Real-affinity columns (`REAL`, `FLOAT`, `DOUBLE`) are similar, except that they attempt to convert strings into `REAL` values instead of `INTEGER` values.  Numeric-affinity columns (`NUMERIC`, `DECIMAL`) convert strings to numbers, but will happily allow `INTEGER` and `REAL` values in the same column.

Text-affinity columns (`CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `TEXT`, `CLOB`) will make the opposite conversion: All numbers (integer or real) are converted to strings.

Blob-affinity columns (`BLOB` or no declared data type) leave all values as-is.

Comment: Nice answer -- I'd also point out dynamically-typed languages can be contrasted with strongly-typed languages (In that they are the basically opposite).  Most popular languages these days are strongly-typed, this is probably the reason for the OP's concern.

Comment: @Hogan: The antonym of “dynamically-typed” is “static-typed”.  “Strong” and “weak” typing are ill-defined terms that basically mean “a type system I like” versus “a type system I don't like”.

Comment: I think the terms means more than that, wikipedia has an entry for example -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing While the term may not be in vogue now I'm sure I could find a dozen textbooks that support this distinction which I think is useful.  Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

The actual value determines the type.
Similar to Excel.

You don't even have to define types for columns, e.g. -

```
create table t (c1,c2,c3);
```

https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

> 1. Datatypes In SQLite
>
> Most SQL database engines (every SQL database engine other than
>   SQLite, as far as we know) uses static, rigid typing. With static
>   typing, the datatype of a value is determined by its container - the
>   particular column in which the value is stored.
>
> SQLite uses a more general dynamic type system. In SQLite, the
>   datatype of a value is associated with the value itself, not with its
>   container. The dynamic type system of SQLite is backwards compatible
>   with the more common static type systems of other database engines in
>   the sense that SQL statements that work on statically typed databases
>   should work the same way in SQLite. However, the dynamic typing in
>   SQLite allows it to do things which are not possible in traditional
>   rigidly typed databases.

---

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t (studentId int);
insert into t (studentId) values (1),(2),('Say what?'),(3),('Yep!');
select studentId from t;
```

> ```
> sqlite> drop table if exists t;
> sqlite> create table t (studentId int);
> sqlite> insert into t (studentId) values (1),(2),('Say what?'),(3),('Yep!');
> sqlite> select studentId from t;
> studentId
> ----------
> 1
> 2
> Say what?
> 3
> Yep!
> ```

```
sqlite> .header on
sqlite> drop table t;
sqlite> create table t (studentId text);
sqlite> insert into t (studentId) values (1),(2),('Say what?'),(3),('Yep!');
sqlite> select studentId,studentId * 10 from t;
studentId   studentId * 10
----------  --------------
1           10
2           20
Say what?   0
3           30
Yep!        0
```

Comment: So it means that my studentId which i want to be integer can be an int for one student and a string for another? How is that good? Where will that help me?

Comment: @Tuhoaminen, re-edited. DbVisualizer cause text to appear as zeros. In sqlite shell it is being displayed correctly.

Comment: @Tuhoaminen: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890462/when-is-sqlites-manifest-typing-useful

Comment: @dan04, personally I think it is a disaster waiting to happen. Like programming language with the same concept, great for ad-hoc tasks, endless source of pain for structured development.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: Well, if you want to actually enforce column type restrictions in SQLite, you can do it with `CHECK` constraints or triggers.  I do wish they'd provide a more convenient way, though.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is wrong to say that in SQLite if you declare an INT column it will only accept integer values.  In SQLite, you can store any datatype in any column.  Therefore, you can declare the column AGE INTEGER and store the value 'I am pretty old', of type TEXT in that column.

This is quite different from virtually every other relational database, which requires the type of the value to match the type of the column it is stored in.

Comment: So it means that my studentId which i want to be integer can be an int for one student and a string for another? How is that good? Where will that help me?

Comment: I didn't say it was good, just that it was.  However, it actually fits well with dynamic languages like Python or Javascript in which you may not actually care so much what type something is, just how it acts.